# Insert an PostScript object in constrained location

Tags: postscript

I have a PostScript object having a known bbox. I want to insert this object into the current image where I known the bbox which this inserted object should have in the current user space. How can I calculate, in PostScript code, the transformation matrix which should be concatenated to the CTM in order to get the expected result ? Note that translation, scaling and rotation may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Scale the existing box down the unit square. `1 width div 1 height div scale`
2. Scale it up to the desired dimensions. `wid hgt scale`

(3. Adjust position if necessary)